# Are there any 6-level-spell progression classes with wildshape?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wild-shape, spellcasting, class

I don't see anything in the plain class descriptions and it's time consuming to go through each archetype to see if I can find what I'm looking for.

Are there any classes that gain access to wild shape and six levels of spells (as opposed to the Druid with 9)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Meet the [Hunter](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/hunter/) ([Feral Hunter](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/hunter/archetypes/paizo-hunter-archetypes/feral-hunter)).

The Hunter is a hybrid class introduced in *Advanced Class Guide*, and is a mix between a Ranger and Druid.  In many ways it is halfway between the two, both in martial capability and spellcasting capability.  The Hunter follows a 3/4 BAB progression like a Druid. The Hunter also uses both the Druid's and Ranger's spell lists, but has a 2/3 spell progression that advances up to 6th level spells.

The base Hunter class relies heavily on teamwork feats and its Animal Companion, which receives greater bonuses compared to the animal companions of a Ranger or Druid.

However, the [Feral Hunter](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/hunter/archetypes/paizo-hunter-archetypes/feral-hunter) archetype trades out its Animal Companion features and most bonus feats, and in exchange gets extra polymorphing and summoning capabilities.  At 4th level, they get a limited version of the druid's Wild Shape feature.

> At 4th level, a feral hunter gains the ability to change shape. This ability functions like the druid wild shape ability, except the hunter can take only animal forms (not elemental or plant forms). The hunter’s effective druid level is equal to her class level.

Comment: Balance Suggestion - The Hunter isn't a brokenly powerful class. If you take away just the upgrades to the Animal Companion, instead of the entire class feature in exchange for the Wild Shape feature, it still ends up as a neatly okay class.

Comment: I would keep an eye on that homerule because the Hunter gets some powerful options with their Animal Companion, including their Focus and powerful [Tricks](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo-ranger-archetypes/skirmisher/). It probably still won't break anything, but an optimized Hunter can cause issues.